# Need a .bat script to delete a folder from all the user profiles windows 7 OS

Tags: batch-file

I need to have a .bat script which can delete a folder with the same name exists in all the user profiles.

I have windows 7 machine in which i have around 3 user accounts.

1) user1, 2) user2 and 3) user3

The folder is there in all the user's desktop namely "123" that should be deleted from all the user profile. I have a code which runs perfectly for the current logged in user but it is not running for the remaining users.

del /Q "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\123"

Need your help on this. please assist me.

Thanks, Raja.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you: run with admin permissions.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\users"
for /d %%a in (*) do rd /s /q "c:\users\%%a\desktop\123" >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: I fixed a flaw in the path - if you notice that a suggestion doesn't work then please say so.

Answer (score 0):

RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\folder path"

make a dot bat file and in the path after %USERNAME% enter the correct path and it will delete that folder from all you profiles.
but if you have  different profiles on the same machine then run the bat file from each user profile.